# Minecraft limit to book reading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway to set it that only a player with a certain level can read a book?
Exp. i have a magic tome and i want it that only players that have 10 level of exp. to open it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
But you can make it so when they reach 10 XP levels, the empty book in their inventory (make it so it was originally empty) is replaced with a written book like this:

- Place a command  block with a redstone comparator coming out of it, with the command `/testfor @p[lm=10]` This will  test if the *closest player* to the command block has 10 XP levels. If they do, a signal will be sent through the redstone comparator to...
- Place another command block in the direction the redstone comparator is facing. This will be the command block that gives the player the book. You can add another command block here too if you want to clear an empty book from the player's inventory. The `/give` command for the book is: `/give KingBspd written_book 1 0 {title:"Book name",author:"Your name",pages:["{text:\"John woke up\nJhon went to work\"}"]}`, but you can find more info on that online.

If you need any additional help, leave a comment.